# border color change on weekends and bank holidays in Crystal Reports calendar

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm writing a report in Crystal Reports where it basically shows an annual calendar of all the different types of absences employees might have had during the year, though my client said he wants to see the weekends marked differently.

I have tried using a formula on the borders this way:

```
IF DayOfWeek (CurrentDate) = 7 or DayOfWeek (CurrentDate) = 1 then crRed
else crNoColor
```

No error is given, but nothing is presented in red on the report once I generate it when its Saturday or Sunday.

Am I going the right way?

Comment: Is there a reason you are evaluating CurrentDate in your DayOfWeek functions?  This will only give you the day of the week for the day the report is executed.  If you want to run this report on any day of the week, and recolor dates that fall on a weekend, you will want to replace CurrentDate with the date for that day on the calendar.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your reply. In the meanwhile I understood what I was doing wrong and obviously I cannot run CurrentDate() inside DayOfWeek()... 

This report will generate a row for each month depending if that month is processed in our application. I'm not actually writting the whole calendar in Crystal Reports.

Can I write a formula to look up the day of each month and know if it was a Saturday or Sunday?

Comment: Yes, you can do that using the `DayOfWeek()` function, just replace `CurrentDate` with the date you need to check.  For example, `DayOfWeek(1990,10,1)` wiill return a value of 2, which indicates that October 1, 1990 was a Monday.